# How can I choose a random turtle to move a random amount of steps?

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Im making a turtle race where 5 different turtles are racing each other and they each take a random amount of steps. But how do I make it that it also chooses a random turtle to move a random number of steps? I can't find a way to make the program choose a turtle. I already tried to make a library of colors and then make the colors turtles and choose a random color (someone on reddit suggested this) but that just added a turtle in the middle of the screen that didn't stop going forward. so i tried:

```
colours = ("red","blue","green","yellow","purple")
turtles = {colour: turtle.Turtle() for colour in colours}
ranTur = turtles[random.choice(colours)]
```

This is exactly what someone on reddit gave me but this didn't work. I want the program to choose one of my 5 turtles that are racing (i have more turtles but they are for drawing the lanes and stuff) and then make that turtle move forward x spaces. And just doing ranTur = ["red","blue","green","yellow","purple"] didn't work either. Is there a way to choose random turtles? Or is that just not possible?

This is my code without that part:

```
import turtle
import random
import time

#turtles
red = turtle.Turtle()
blue = turtle.Turtle()
green = turtle.Turtle()
yellow = turtle.Turtle()
purple = turtle.Turtle()
lijn = turtle.Turtle()
winner1 = turtle.Turtle()
winner2 = turtle.Turtle()
arrowR = turtle.Turtle()
arrowB = turtle.Turtle()
arrowG = turtle.Turtle()
arrowY = turtle.Turtle()
arrowP = turtle.Turtle()

#font
fontLines = ("Arial", 16, "normal")

#turtle colors
red.color("red")
blue.color("blue")
green.color("green")
yellow.color("yellow")
purple.color("purple")
lijn.color("black")
winner1.color("black")
arrowR.color("red")
arrowB.color("blue")
arrowG.color("green")
arrowY.color("yellow")
arrowP.color("purple")

#turtle penup
red.penup()
blue.penup()
green.penup()
yellow.penup()
purple.penup()
winner1.penup()
winner2.penup()
arrowR.penup()
arrowB.penup()
arrowG.penup()
arrowY.penup()
arrowP.penup()
lijn.penup()

#turtle shapes
red.shape("turtle")
blue.shape("turtle")
green.shape("turtle")
yellow.shape("turtle")
purple.shape("turtle")
arrowR.shape("arrow")
arrowB.shape("arrow")
arrowG.shape("arrow")
arrowY.shape("arrow")
arrowP.shape("arrow")

#turtle speed
arrowR.speed(0)
arrowB.speed(0)
arrowG.speed(0)
arrowY.speed(0)
arrowP.speed(0)
red.speed(0)
blue.speed(0)
green.speed(0)
yellow.speed(0)
purple.speed(0)
winner1.speed(0)
winner2.speed(0)
lijn.speed(0)

#hide turtles
arrowR.hideturtle()
arrowB.hideturtle()
arrowG.hideturtle()
arrowY.hideturtle()
arrowP.hideturtle()
winner1.hideturtle()
winner2.hideturtle()
lijn.hideturtle()

#arrow positions
arrowR.goto(-190,70)
arrowB.goto(-190,35)
arrowG.goto(-190,0)
arrowY.goto(-190,-35)
arrowP.goto(-190,-70)

#start turtles
xBegin = -180
def raceTur():
    red.goto(-180,70)
    blue.goto(-180,35)
    green.goto(-180,0)
    yellow.goto(-180,-35)
    purple.goto(-180,-70)

raceTur()

#race lanes
def line(x,y,width,text):
    lijn.penup()
    lijn.goto(x,y)
    
    for i in range (15):
        lijn.write(text, font=fontLines)
        lijn.forward(width)
    
def raceBaan():
    line(-150,60,20,"|")
    line(-150,25,20,"|")
    line(-150,-10,20,"|")
    line(-150,-45,20,"|")
    line(-150,-80,20,"|")

raceBaan()

# reset
def reset():
    raceTur()
    raceBaan()
    
    
#numbers
lijn.goto(-150,90)
lijn.write("0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10     11     12     13     14")

#winner text
winner1.goto(xBegin,-180)
winner1.write("De winnaar is: ",font=("Arial",30,"normal"))
winner2.goto(20,-180)

#finish line
finishLine = 140

#race
def Race():
    while True:
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        red.forward(x)
        if red.xcor() > blue.xcor() and red.xcor() > green.xcor() and red.xcor() > yellow.xcor() and red.xcor() > purple.xcor():
            arrowR.showturtle()
        else:
            arrowR.hideturtle()
        if red.pos()[0]>=finishLine:
            winner2.color("red")
            winner2.write("rood",font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
            break
        
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        blue.forward(x)
        if blue.xcor() > red.xcor() and blue.xcor() > green.xcor() and blue.xcor() > yellow.xcor() and blue.xcor() > purple.xcor():
            arrowB.showturtle()
        else:
            arrowB.hideturtle()
        if blue.pos()[0]>=finishLine:
            winner2.color("blue")
            winner2.write("blauw",font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
            break
        
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        green.forward(x)
        if green.xcor() > red.xcor() and green.xcor() > blue.xcor() and green.xcor() > yellow.xcor() and green.xcor() > purple.xcor():
            arrowG.showturtle()
        else:
            arrowG.hideturtle()
        if green.pos()[0]>=finishLine:
            winner2.color("green")
            winner2.write("groen",font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
            break
        
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        yellow.forward(x)
        if yellow.xcor() > red.xcor() and yellow.xcor() > green.xcor() and yellow.xcor() > blue.xcor() and yellow.xcor() > purple.xcor():
            arrowY.showturtle()
        else:
            arrowY.hideturtle()
        if yellow.pos()[0]>=finishLine:
            winner2.color("yellow")
            winner2.write("geel",font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
            break
        
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        purple.forward(x)
        if purple.xcor() > blue.xcor() and purple.xcor() > green.xcor() and purple.xcor() > yellow.xcor() and purple.xcor() > red.xcor():
            arrowP.showturtle()
        else:
            arrowP.hideturtle()
        if purple.pos()[0]>=finishLine:
            winner2.color("purple")
            winner2.write("paars",font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
            break
    time.sleep(3)
    winner2.clear()
    arrowR.hideturtle()
    arrowB.hideturtle()
    arrowG.hideturtle()
    arrowY.hideturtle()
    arrowP.hideturtle()
    reset()
    Race()    
        
Race()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: That code looks like it should work - with the understanding that the assignments to `color` and `turtles` are things that you do once, before the start of the game, and the assignment to `ranTur` is something you do each time you want to choose a random turtle.  Please be more specific than "this didn't work" to describe the problem you have with it.

Comment: i placed the colours and turtles piece of code in between the def Race(): and the finishLine and i replaced all the red.forward(x) etc with ranTur.forward(x). When i run it, everything gets drawn. the 5 colored turtles dont move, but a new turtle (black triangle) shows up in the middle of the screen and it keeps going forward x steps and it doesnt stop.

Comment: Did you assign colors to the five turtles you're choosing from for `ranTur`?  Just because they have names like "red", doesn't make them actually red...

Comment: yes i gave all my turtles a color, its the second big block of code from the top. do i need to give them other names? do the colors and the names like clash? i just gave them the colors as names because it was easier for me

Comment: `{colour: turtle.Turtle() for colour in colours}` is creating five brand-new turtles, all with default values.  They have *absolutely nothing* to do with the existing turtles in your code.

Comment: oh oops :/ how do i connect them? or how do i change it so that they do? or is that not possible

Answer (score 0):

[image]

### Is there a way to choose random turtles? Or is that just not possible?

The simple answer is: it is possible using the **`random.choice(list_of_turtles)`** function of the random module. It chooses a random item from a list of items and is used along with `random.randint(1,10)` for a *random choice of the step **and** the turtle to move*

Change in your script the code at the end to:

```
#finish line
finishLine = 140

dict_of_turtles = {
red     : ( arrowR , "red"   , "rood"  ),
blue    : ( arrowB , "blue"  , "blauw" ),
green   : ( arrowG , "green" , "groen" ),
yellow  : ( arrowY , "yellow", "geel"  ),
purple  : ( arrowP , "purple", "paars" ),
}
list_of_turtles = list( dict_of_turtles.keys() )

def Race():
    
    while True: 
        random_turtle = random.choice(list_of_turtles)
        other_turtles = list_of_turtles[:] ; other_turtles.remove(random_turtle)
        arrow_turtle, turtle_color, turtle_color_text  = dict_of_turtles[random_turtle]
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        random_turtle.forward(x)
        if all( random_turtle.xcor() > other.xcor() for other in other_turtles):
            arrow_turtle.showturtle()
        else:
            arrow_turtle.hideturtle()
        if random_turtle.pos()[0] >= finishLine:
            winner2.color(turtle_color)
            winner2.write(turtle_color_text,font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
            break

    time.sleep(3)
    winner2.clear()
    arrowR.hideturtle()
    arrowB.hideturtle()
    arrowG.hideturtle()
    arrowY.hideturtle()
    arrowP.hideturtle()
    reset()
    Race()    
        
Race()

turtle.done()
```

end enjoy the racing and the much shorter script as there is no need to move within each loop all of the turtles.

For the sake of completeness below a reworked full version of the original code to run focused on making the code a bit more compact and 'Pythonic' along with providing the requested feature of random choice of turtle to move.

```
import turtle
import random
import time
screen = turtle.Screen()
colors_EN       = ['red',   'blue', 'green','yellow', 'purple']
colors_NL       = ["rood", "blauw", "groen",  "geel", "paars" ]
len_list        = len(colors_EN)
turtles_racing  = [ turtle.Turtle() for t in range(len_list)]
arrow_turtles   = [ turtle.Turtle() for t in range(len_list)]
lines_and_texts = [ turtle.Turtle() for t in range(4)]
lines_and_texts[1].color("black")
fontLines = ("Arial", 16, "normal")
#turtle colors
for indx, color in enumerate(colors_EN):
    turtles_racing[indx].color(color); arrow_turtles[indx].color(color) 
#turtle penup and speed
for turtleObjectItem in turtles_racing+arrow_turtles+lines_and_texts: 
    turtleObjectItem.penup() 
    turtleObjectItem.speed(0) 
#turtle shapes
for turtleObjectItem in turtles_racing: turtleObjectItem.shape("turtle")
for turtleObjectItem in arrow_turtles:  turtleObjectItem.shape("arrow")
#hide turtles
for turtleObjectItem in arrow_turtles+lines_and_texts: 
    turtleObjectItem.hideturtle() 
# arrow positions
arrow_turtles[0].goto(-190, 70) # R
arrow_turtles[1].goto(-190, 35) # B
arrow_turtles[2].goto(-190,  0) # G
arrow_turtles[3].goto(-190,-35) # Y
arrow_turtles[4].goto(-190,-70) # P
#start turtles
xBegin = -180
def prepStart():
    turtles_racing[0].goto(-180, 70)
    turtles_racing[1].goto(-180, 35)
    turtles_racing[2].goto(-180,  0)
    turtles_racing[3].goto(-180,-35)
    turtles_racing[4].goto(-180,-70)
    for turtleObjectItem in arrow_turtles: 
        turtleObjectItem.hideturtle()
prepStart()

#race lanes
def line(x,y,width,text):
    lines_and_texts[0].penup()
    lines_and_texts[0].goto(x,y)
    
    for i in range (15):
        lines_and_texts[0].write(text, font=fontLines)
        lines_and_texts[0].forward(width)
def raceBaan():
    line(-150,60,20,"|")
    line(-150,25,20,"|")
    line(-150,-10,20,"|")
    line(-150,-45,20,"|")
    line(-150,-80,20,"|")
raceBaan()

#numbers
lines_and_texts[0].goto(-150,90)
lines_and_texts[0].write("0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10     11     12     13     14")

#winner text
lines_and_texts[1].goto(xBegin,-180)
lines_and_texts[1].write("De winnaar is: "            , font=("Arial",30,"normal"))
lines_and_texts[2].goto(100,-230) # -180)
lines_and_texts[3].goto(xBegin,150)
lines_and_texts[3].color("#abcdef")
lines_and_texts[3].write(" Quit racing event with 'q'", font=("Arial",15,"bold"))

finishLine = 140
# QUIT by pressing 'q' on the keyboard
screen.quit = False
def quit():
    screen.quit = True if not screen.quit else False
screen.onkey(quit, "q")

def eventloop():
    while True: 
        i = index_random_turtle = random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) # or randint(0,4)
        random_turtle = turtles_racing[i]
        other_turtles = turtles_racing[:] ; other_turtles.pop(i)
        arrow_turtle  = arrow_turtles[i]
        turtle_color  = colors_EN[i]
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        random_turtle.forward(x)
        if all( random_turtle.xcor() > other.xcor() for other in other_turtles):
            arrow_turtle.showturtle()
        else:
            arrow_turtle.hideturtle()
        if random_turtle.pos()[0] >= finishLine:
            lines_and_texts[2].color(turtle_color)
            lines_and_texts[2].write(turtle_color,font=("Arial",30,"bold"))
            break

    time.sleep(3)
    lines_and_texts[2].clear()
    prepStart()
    if not screen.quit: 
        screen.ontimer(eventloop, 10) # 10ms (0.01s) (1000ms/10ms = 100 FPS)
    else: 
        screen.bye()
#:def eventloop()

eventloop()
screen.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```